# how to use materialize-stepper with angular

Tags: angular, materialize, materialize-stepper

I am using [materialize-stepper](https://kinark.github.io/Materialize-stepper/) with angular 6. From the documentation I have to write some HTML and then initialize DOM element like

```
let stepperInstace = new MStepper(stepper, {
      // options
      firstActive: 0 // this is the default
})
```

And the HTML

```
<ul class="stepper linear" #contentTypeStepper>
    <li class="step active">
        <div class="step-title waves-effect">E-mail</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <!-- Your step content goes here (like inputs or so) -->
            <div class="step-actions">
                <!-- Here goes your actions buttons -->
                <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn next-step">CONTINUE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="step">
        <div class="step-title waves-effect">Data</div>
        <div class="step-content">
            <!-- Your step content goes here (like inputs or so) -->
            <div class="step-actions">
                <!-- Here goes your actions buttons -->
                <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn next-step">CONTINUE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS entry in **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
       "node_modules/materialize-stepper/dist/css/mstepper.css"
]
```

In the ts I am importing it like

```
import MStepper from "materialize-stepper/dist/js/mstepper";

@ViewChild("contentTypeStepper")
contentTypeStepper: ElementRef;

iContentTypeStepper: any;
```

and initializing it like

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("TCL: AdminContentTypeDetailComponent -> MStepper", MStepper);
    this.iContentTypeStepper = MStepper.constructor(this.contentTypeStepper.nativeElement, {
          firstActive: 0 // this is the default
    });

}
```

but this is not working. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library hasn't been properly modularized which makes it a bit more obtuse to work with. There are posts out there on how to create a `.d.ts` file for the library in order to use the `import` syntax for a library like this. I have often found that it is easier to not do that though.

The easiest way to work with this library in Angular is to make it a 'globally' available library.

In your **angular.json** file, make sure you have

```
"node_modules/materialize-stepper/dist/css/mstepper.css"
```

in your scripts property.

And in your `styles` property(as you have listed above. Also put

```
"node_modules/materialize-stepper/dist/js/mstepper.js"
```

Then in your `ts` file, replace

```
import MStepper from "materialize-stepper/dist/js/mstepper";
```

with

```
declare const MStepper: any;
```

With that in place, your above code should work.